# Hadoop MapReduce throughput question

Tags: performance, hadoop

I am interesting - what can be considered to be a good throughput
for the hadoop lightweight text data processing per node? 
 To be more specific I would ask:
Let say I have to read csv files, parse them and count number of specific values in some column. Lets assume that values are rare so the reduce step is fast.  
What throughput can I expect per hadoop node from the modern quad core CPU / 4 GB RAM / 4 SATA Disk machines?

Comment: I think this is almost impossible to answer as exact implementation, data source and configuration will have a huge impact on the results.

Comment: I understand that it is no exact answer. But at least order of magnitude should be known (IMHO). For the RDBMS based solution I can take TPCH Q1 (for example) and see the throupput. I would like to understand - is it 1 MB/sec, 10 MB/sec, 100 or 300 MB/sec. It is important to know when I am planning the solution and have to know how many machines customer need to buy.

Comment: @David Gruzman: why don't you test it on a 'grunty' PC?

Comment: Sure I did. I am getting about 10-20 MB sec using sinlge node cluster, or 100 Mb/sec on 6 node. I would like to understand - am I doing good related to others. May be there are some fundamental optimizations when working with text file, which I am missing.

Comment: How about giving your clusterconfiguration? How many maps are you using?

Comment: I am using 6 maps per node - can not do more because of memory constraints.

Comment: You could adjust the buffer size to pre-buffer the text lines hadoop will parse. I don't think that lightweight text processing will take roughly about 600mb for each map task. You could increase the mappers per node and get a much better speedup.

Answer (score 1):

I find the question reasonable. I get an impression of a hadoop clusters throughput with

```
(SizeOfInput + SizeOfOutput) / RuntimeInSeconds / NumberOfDisks
```

For the [yahoo PB-Sort](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/posts/2009/05/hadoop_sorts_a_petabyte_in_162/) that run on 3800 nodes **with commodity hardware** (2 disks per node), that simple expression evaluates to: 2.24 MB/(s and disk).

For jobs that are IO bound (search for DFSIO tests), you'll find clusters with around 20 MB/(s and disk).

I think you won't find a hadoop cluster with commodity hardware right now that has much more than 20MB/(s and disk) on IO bound jobs. But I may be wrong.

Comment: Nice article about the math behind clusters: http://nathanmarz.com/blog/the-mathematics-behind-hadoop-based-systems.html